# Detecting new device insert in C++

Tags: c++, mfc, device

I've tried to find a way to detect when a new device (like a USB) is inserted into a computer, but everything I've seen required MFC, which I don't have. Is there a way to do this without MFC? If not, I understand, but I haven't seen anything of the like in my Google searches.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

C++ by itself does not have any platform-dependent hardware-level functionality. You will need to use *some* API, like Win32 or MFC or .NET on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [libusb](http://libusb.org) and there's a port of [libusb for win32](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-win32), so you might have some luck using that instead of MFC, with the added bonus of being more portable.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the WM_DEVICECHANGE message.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT: Of course, this is Windows only, which the OP didn't specify. There's no way to do this without external libraries or platform specific APIs.